# How to create a theme function for custom HTML markup and then call it in my node template?

Tags: theming

Ive created an asses for my site in the content type tpl file. Its mainly HTML but also some simple PHP. What are the steps to move this to a theme function?

Comment: What do you mean by "asses"?

Comment: Its a section of the page, so basically some HTML.

Comment: Based on your other comment on an answer it seems like what you want to do is "How to create a theme function for custom HTML markup and then call it in my node template?".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) function to move your logic from your tpl files into the theme function. In order to use the function, replace template with the name of your theme.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&variables){
  if($variables['node']->type == 'my_content_type'){
    //change what you want to the node here.
  }
}
```

You could do the logic you need to inside this functionn, save the output to a variable in $variable (it's a reference var, so it dosn't need to be returned) and then just print out that variable in your tpl.php file.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me. I have some HTML written directly into the node tpl. I want to move this into a new tpl file and load that file into the node tpl. I would also like a theme function so down the line I can add some configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put what you need in a regular PHP file in your theme directory. In the tpl file just do a PHP include call.

```
<?php include("your_html.php"); ?>
```

Comment: I would like to be able to add configuration later, eg chose from 2 similar layouts.

Comment: Okay well for the HTML inclusion I'd recommend PHP inclusion. Look at [template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) and other preprocessor functions for your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In template.php:

```
THEMENAME_theme() {
    $themes = array (
        'THEMENAME_FEATURENAME' => array(
            'template' => 'templates/TPL-FILE-NAME',
            'arguments' => array('id' => null),
        ),
    );
    return $themes;
}
```

In content type tpl file:

```
<?php print theme('THEMENAME_FEATURE'); ?>
```

In my templates folder is TPL-FILE-NAME.tpl.php

This does pull in HTML from the tpl.php file however PHP such as `<?php print $title; ?>` and `<?php print $GLOBALS['$base_url'] . $node_url ?>` no long work (they did when they were in the content type tpl file).

Also a paid video here: https://drupalize.me/videos/strategies-keeping-template-files-clean?p=1146